# Add spaces/margin between bars - Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, frontend, chart.js, bar-chart

How can I add white spaces/margin between bars with Chart.js 3.0 ? I didn't find anything to process like the image

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1SvV.png)

My code looks like this and makes this :
[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0mOd.png)

```
datasets: [{
                categoryPercentage: 1.0,
                barPercentage: 0.8,
            }]
        },
    options: {
            onHover() {},
            indexAxis: 'y',
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
     }
```

full code here : https://codepen.io/mateofaivre/pen/zYdYgmB

Comment: Hello, could you try to provide some code and the things you have tried. It helps to understand your problem a bit better so people can help you easier.

Comment: hello, yes sorry, edited

Comment: Yes, it produces same result as my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the `categoryPercentage` to lower value like 0.8 and `barPercentage` to 1.

Graphical info about categoryPercentage vs barPercentage:

```
// categoryPercentage: 1.0
// barPercentage: 1.0
Bar:        | 1.0 | 1.0 |
Category:   |    1.0    |
Sample:     |===========|

// categoryPercentage: 1.0
// barPercentage: 0.5
Bar:          |.5|  |.5|
Category:  |      1.0     |
Sample:    |==============|

// categoryPercentage: 0.5
// barPercentage: 1.0
Bar:             |1.0||1.0|
Category:        |   .5   |
Sample:     |==================|
```

**EDIT:**

You can get the bar width from the metasets of the chart and use that to draw it on the chart like so:

```js
const plugin = {
  id: 'background',
  beforeDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
    if (!opts.color) {
      return;
    }

    const {
      ctx,
      chartArea,
      _metasets
    } = chart;

    ctx.fillStyle = opts.color;

    _metasets.forEach(meta => {
      meta.data.forEach(data => {
        if (data.horizontal) {
          ctx.fillRect(chartArea.left, (data.y - (data.height / 2)), chartArea.width, data.height)
        } else {
          ctx.fillRect((data.x - (data.width / 2)), chartArea.top, data.width, chartArea.height)
        }
      })
    });
  }
}

Chart.register(plugin);

var colors = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  colors.push('#5671DB');
}
var config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Commerce, vente', 'Transport', 'Bureautique', 'Accueil', 'Santé', 'Secrétariat', 'Nettoyage', 'Sécurité', 'Mécanique', 'Agro-alimentaire'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [23.8, 17.7, 13, 9.5, 7.8, 7, 5.5, 5, 4.5, 3.5],
      backgroundColor: colors,
      hoverBackgroundColor: colors,
      borderColor: colors,
    }],
  },
  options: {
    onHover() {},
    indexAxis: 'y',
    barPercentage: 0.8,
    //barThickness: 60,
    // maxBarThickness: 60,
    categoryPercentage: 1.0,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      background: {
        color: '#CDECEF'
      },
      title: {
        display: false,
        text: "Les 10 principaux domaines d'emploi",
        align: 'start',
        fullSize: true,
        color: '#324488',
        font: {
          size: 24,
          family: 'Arial',
        }
      },
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
        displayColors: false,
        titleFont: {
          size: 0,
        },
        titleMarginBottom: 0,
        titleSpacing: 0,
        bodyFont: {
          size: 25,
          weight: 700
        },
        xAlign: 'right',
        callbacks: {
          label: (item) => (`${item.parsed.x} %`),
        },
      },
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        ticks: {
          color: "#34478B",
          font: {
            size: 18,
          },
          stepSize: 1,
          beginAtZero: true
        },
      },
      x: {
        ticks: {
          color: "#25C8C9",
          font: {
            size: 14
          },
          stepSize: 1,
          beginAtZero: true
        },

      }
    }
  },
};


var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

[codePen](https://codepen.io/leelenaleee/pen/mdMyyXX)

Comment: Thanks, but It not makes what I want :/

Comment: Please share your whole code then because if you put it correctly it should work

Comment: https://codepen.io/mateofaivre/pen/zYdYgmB

Comment: Next time please include your code in your question because what you want is not margin between bars, you want gaps in the background you are drawing using a custom plugin so no way people could help you

Comment: and if i don't use a plugin for the background it's possible ?

Comment: As you can see in my live example with a plugin its possible, otherwise you will need to use an extra dataset and make the data stacked but that will be more config work since you need to calculate all bar heights yourself and make sure the max of the scale is set correctly

Answer (score 0):

If reducing the bar size is not a problem you could add barPercentage to your options.

Like this:

```
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    barPercentage: 0.8
  }
};
```

[Bar Chart | Charts.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/charts/bar.html#barpercentage)

Comment: Thnaks, but It not makes what I want :/