# How can I adjust the width between 2 specific columns of bar chart of Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, chart.js2, chart.js3

How can I adjust the width between 2 specific columns of the bar chart of Chart.js?

[image: Screenshot]

I want to distance certain 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will help you but I found this
[Add spaces/margin between bars - Chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69495451/add-spaces-margin-between-bars-chart-js)

I think it should help

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it is good idea but why didn't you try to use two charts with different settings and to place them in layout next to each other